# Make object Small time by time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i want to make my object smaller and smaller time by time i used code but its not giving output as i want can anybody get me rid of this problem waiting for reply thanks in advance here is my code ..

```
if(hit.collider.gameObject.name=="up" && liftUp)
{
    for (j =27, k=91, l=30; j>=0; j--,k--,l--)
    {    
        //j=n;
        //WaitForSeconds(2);    
        StartCoroutine(waitForScalling ());
        print("sdjaklj");
        dirt.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (j,k,l);
     }
}

IEnumerator waitForScalling()
{    
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.2f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way would be to do this:

```
    Vector3 finaleSize = dirt.transform.localScale * 0.1f;

    /*
    *
    *
    */

    if(hit.collider.gameObject.name == "up" && liftUp)
        dirt.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(dirt.transform.scale, finaleSize, Time.deltaTime);
```